# Animations on the view happens only on First Time

Tags: java, android, search, android-animation

I am doing customized search bar like WhatsApp, google apps.I am trying to add animation while showing and closing the view.I add animation XML files to do these things.

Suppose, if the user presses the search icon, it will display the search bar with animation. if the user presses the close icon in the search bar, it will close the search bar with animation.

Animation happens only in First time.It doesn't animate for the second time like when I press the search icon.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Animation.AnimationListener{
ImageButton ibSearch;
EditText etSearch;
ImageButton ibBack,ibClose;
CardView cardView;
ObjectAnimator objectanimator;
RelativeLayout search;
Animation animOpenView,animCloseView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ibSearch = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.search);
    cardView = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.searchBarC);
    ibClose = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.close);
    search = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.searchLayout);
    animOpenView = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
            R.anim.anim_left);
    animCloseView = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
            R.anim.anim_right);

    animCloseView.setAnimationListener(this);
    animOpenView.setAnimationListener(this);

    ibSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            cardView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            cardView.setAnimation(animOpenView);

        }
    });
    ibClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            cardView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            cardView.setAnimation(animCloseView);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

}

@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

}

@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are making your view **gone**

> your view is going off the screen before the animation starts..

so **to enjoy  the animation just remove that line..**

`cardView.setVisibility(View.GONE); // remove this..
            cardView.setAnimation(animCloseView);`

Comment: no man.it works for the first time.i don't know how to reinitiate the animation.

Comment: 1st click on ibOpen shows `openanim...` 2nd click will have problem because you are setting gone before colse anim

Comment: but even though I add close anim before hiding the view, it's not working.the problem is we need to reinitiate the animation.

Comment: I solved this issue.I did reassign the animCloseView and animOpenView.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your activity's `onAnimationEnd`:

```
@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    cardView.clearAnimation();
}
```

Comment: no, it's not working.happens only for the first time

Comment: I solved this issue.I did reassign the animCloseView and animOpenView.

Comment: Post your solution as a separate answer

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed.Actually, the issue was,animCloseView and animOpenView get empty/non-null after the first time.So I reinitiate the anims.

```
ibSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                cardView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                animOpenView = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.anim.anim_left); //just added this line
                cardView.setAnimation(animOpenView);

            }
        });
        ibClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                cardView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                animCloseView = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.anim.anim_right); //just added this line
                cardView.setAnimation(animCloseView);
            }
        });
    }
```